# InvocationTargetException: Dapp call failed when using Aion Embedded AVM

Tags: java, blockchain, aion

I'm getting the following message when I call my contract using maven and the embedded AVM:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.aion4j:aion4j-maven-plugin:0.5.0-beta1:call (default-cli) on project supercontract: Method call failed: InvocationTargetException: Dapp call failed. Code: FAILED, Reason: null -> [Help 1]
```

I just edited the `HelloAvM` contract that you get when you `mvn initialize` the project. Here's the whole contract:

```
public class HelloAvm {
    // Voting App
    // 1. Users call a function to find out what the question is.
    // 2. They then call another function with their choice.
    // 3. Any use can call the results() function to find out what the current votes are.

    public static int questionNumber = 1;
    public static String questionString = "Is Haggis a real animal?";

    public String getQuestion() {
        return "Question #" + questionNumber + ": " + questionString;
    }

    public void testContract() {
        // This function just returns a string to show that the contract is working.
        BlockchainRuntime.println("This contract is working.");
    }

    public static byte[] main() {
        return ABIDecoder.decodeAndRunWithClass(HelloAvm.class, BlockchainRuntime.getData());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why it's failing, and the error message isn't much use. I've looked at other InvocationTargetException errors on StackOverflow, but they don't seem to help this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Apparently you need to make each function `static` for Java contracts. So `getQuestion` and `testContract` above should look like this:

```
public static String getQuestion() {
        return "Question #" + questionNumber + ": " + questionString;
    }

    public static void testContract() {
        // This function just returns a string to show that the contract is working.
        BlockchainRuntime.println("This contract is working.");
    }
```